# SQLSTATE 42000 on Restore after restoring native backup from NetBackup tape

Tags: backup-restoration, sql-server, netbackup

My environment is Windows Server Standard 2003 SP2, SQL Server 2000 SP4 with a few additional patches, NetBackup Admin console 7.1 and NetBackup Client 6.5.3.

I take nightly full backups that restore with no problem.  I also perform nightly server backups with NetBackup.  After a native backup has been backed up with NetBackup to tape and subsequently restored to disk from tape it fails with the 'SQL-DMO(ODBC SQLState: 42000) An internal consistency' error.  The RESTORE VERIFYONLY indicates that the backup set is valid.  This restore has been attempted on server native backups with no success.

These restores are being done on the server that acted as the source so there is no issue with patch level, etc. between different servers.

Many other types of files have been restored with no apparent problem (Excel, .pst, .SLS).

Any help with this would be appreciated.

---

The NetBackup strategy currently being used was implemented in March against Virtual Servers on VMWare using the 'flash' methodology.

This error appears only to happen with SQL Server 2000 and .BAK files larger than 2G.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is unlucky enough to encounter this also, check out the link http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH160324 and see that it is a default parameter value that may be causing the problem.  Changing the default value resolved the problem.